# Add the necessary CSS class to the hyperlink in PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Show the code that would go in the Page_Load method of Products.aspx that uses the public property and adds the necessary CSS class to the hyperlink

MasterPage Code :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="MyMaster.master.cs" Inherits="MyMaster.MyMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head id="Head1" runat="server">

<title></title>


<style>

ul {

float: left; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;

list-style-type: none;

}

a {

float: left; width: 6em;

text-decoration: none; color: white; background-color: purple; padding: 0.2em 0.6em;

border-right: 1px solid white;

}

a.selected {

background-color: fuchsia;
}


li {
display: inline;

}

</style> </head> <body>

<form id="form1" runat="server"> <div>

<!--CSS-driven menu --> <ul id="ae" class="selected">

<li><a href="Home.aspx"  >Home</a></li> 
<li id="Product"><a href="Products.aspx" >Products</a></li> 
<li><a href="AboutUs.aspx" >About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="ContactUs.aspx" >Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="FeaturedContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                 </div>

</form> </body> </html>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function mouseUp(element) { element.style.background = 'red'; }
    function mouseDown(element) { element.style.background = 'blue'; }
</script>
```

MyMaster.Master.cs:

```
namespace MyMaster
{
    public partial class MyMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        public String anc
        {
            get { return anc; }
            set { anc = value; }

        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }




    }
}
```

Product.aspx.cs

```
namespace MyMaster
{
    public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MyMaster m = new MyMaster();

             //Master.MasterHyperlink.
             //  Master.MasterHyperlink.Navigateurl = "Products.aspx";
            Control cntb;
            cntb = this.FindControl("ae");
            cntb.CssClass = "Selected";
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the class attribute of an HTML tag in code behind. This won't work unless you add runat="server" to the  tag. this.Findcontrol looks for ASP.Net controls and not for HTML controls. You can achieve this with jQuery easily.